# How to disable submit button once it has been clicked php?

Tags: php, html, onclick

I have a send button at the end of the form but I do not know how to disable it in the onClick.

```
echo "<input type='submit' name='add' value=\"".$LANG['help'][14]."\" class='submit' >";
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use

```
echo "<input type='submit' name='add' onclick="this.form.submit(); this.disabled = true;"  value=\"".$LANG['help'][14]."\" class='submit' >";
```

Comment: The problem is that when using that code the button does not send the form, it is disabled since loading the page.

Comment: are you calling any function for form submission?

Comment: I guess if I call the function, but I do not see it, it's the default GLPI file.

Comment: please use my updated code onclick="this.form.submit(); this.disabled = true;"

Comment: Refresh the form view but not send.

Comment: A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Answer (score 1):

You can try following code

```
echo "<input type='submit' name='add' onclick="this.disabled = true; this.form.submit();"  value=\"".$LANG['help'][14]."\" class='submit' >";
```

Comment: Refresh the form view but not send.

Comment: are you using any function in js to handle form submission ?

Comment: Do or do not. There is no "try". A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Answer (score 0):

please try this

```
$('input[type="submit"]').click(function() {
    this.disabled = true;
};
```

Comment: How would I put that code? I am new to php and when I put it in as well as I left the page blank, could you tell me where I put it?

Comment: Do or do not. There is no "try". A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Comment: Yes, not only the code and I finished, I would like to know the reason of things to learn php.